# Build nodejs typescript project to production

Tags: node.js, typescript

May be a noob question about nodejs and typescript, consider i have **src** folder where all my .ts files are located, and a **lib** folder for compiled files.
When i commit files to ignore **lib** folder from .gitignore file, my question is simple : 
 - the other developper who is charged to pull my changes and start the production node server should compile first .ts files from source ? and then from package.json he target the compiled lib folder to run the script?

Thanks for your light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in TS it's similiar to compiled languages- you have to compile (transpile) project before using it.
The common practice is to use CI/CD to transpile ts files and deploy transpiled ones to production.
If you want to simplify the process of running the application in development environment I recommend you taking a look on ts-node npm package